# Emacs (Aquamacs) org-mode agendas are suddenly empty

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm sorry for this newbie question, but I'M lost at this point:

*I'm using Aquamacs 2.4 on MacOS X 10.6.8 and I'm currently trying to learn emacs and org-mode.*
I have several *.org files containing TODO items and I was able to display an agenda for those files,
however suddenly (I must have changed a configuration, but I don't see what I did wrong) the "standard agenda" (with command "a") is completely empty:

There is only one line "Week-agenda (W06):" nothing else.

However, all org-files are in the agenda file list and if I open one file and choose `Set Restriction Lock` to the current subtree, the rebuilt agenda view gets populated with the items from that subtree. But without the restriction I get an empty agenda again.

How can I switch back to the configuration I had before?
Any ideas what I might have done wrong?

btw: when I invoke the agenda with option "t" (list of all todo entries) it seems to work and I really get this list.

---

EDIT

some more information: it seems to happen when I load my whole org-files directory as "agenda files". Something in there seems to change the agenda configuration.
I'll try to add the files one by one and see when it happens.

Comment: Do you happen to remember making any configuration changes (through customize or .emacs file) of late? (Since you mention you must have).

Comment: it seems, but I don't know what I changed (I did not do it purposeful). I deleted all preferences and configuration files and now it works again... :D

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin: it seems that the change of configuration is made by loading some file as an agenda file... I'll try them out. (see my edit in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `C-c a a` will not show todo tasks unless they are scheduled or have deadline associated with it. So what you seeing is standard thing. you can check this by adding a schedule to any task using `C-c C-s` and see them with `C-c a a` (agenda for current week)

Comment: I DID see tasks with DEADLINE or SCHEDULED dates in the agenda before, but then (after - I assume some magical shortkey) nothing was displayed any more in the "normal" agenda. It seemed to ignore everything.

Comment: @Martin Are you sure you have scheduled/deadlined entries for the current week?  It sounds silly but if that's what happened you would seem to have a blank agenda.

Comment: No, I don't have a blank agenda - I (still) have scheduled and deadline entries for today and the following days but with some strange configuration they seemed all to be hidden (maybe I've added a filter criterion for the agenda) Where are such changes of the configuration saved?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you've removed your documents from the list of agenda files somehow? According to the official page you can add the document with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> to the list of agenda files.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this exact problem randomly starting last week on Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid). My current emacs version is 24.4.1 (I use the Ubuntu package). I have a clocktable at the top of my todo.org, and I found that removing it temporarily fixed this problem for me.